# Performing grep operation in tar files without extracting

Tags: unix

I have list of files which contain particular patterns, but those files have been tarred. Now I want to search for the pattern in the tar file, and to know which files contain the pattern without extracting the files.

Any idea...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to grep for a pattern in the files in tar archive without filling up disk space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041068/how-to-grep-for-a-pattern-in-the-files-in-tar-archive-without-filling-up-disk-sp)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

the `tar` command has a `-O` switch to extract your files to standard output. So you can pipe those output to `grep/awk`

```
tar xvf  test.tar -O | awk '/pattern/{print}'

tar xvf  test.tar -O | grep "pattern"
```

eg to return file name one pattern found

```
tar tf myarchive.tar | while read -r FILE
do
    if tar xf test.tar $FILE  -O | grep "pattern" ;then
        echo "found pattern in : $FILE"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't give the names of matching files.

Comment: So giving the name of one of the tarred up files to tar after the archive file gives only the contents of that file! Where is this documented? Can you please tell?

Comment: @AnkurAgarwal [In the manpage](https://man.archlinux.org/man/tar.1.en#UNIX-style_usage) -- *`-x`, `--extract`, `--get`: Extract files from an archive. Arguments are optional. When given, they specify names of the archive members to be extracted.*

Comment: @AnkurAgarwal Admittedly, [man pages](https://xkcd.com/1692/) are famously [hard to understand](https://xkcd.com/293/). [`tar`'s esepcially.](https://xkcd.com/1168/) (relevant XKCDs)

Answer (score 44):

The command `zgrep` should do exactly what you want, directly.

for example

```
zgrep "mypattern" *.gz
```

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_zgrep.htm

Comment: this question is about tar files, not gzipped.

Comment: `zgrep -a pattern myfile.tar.gz`

Answer (score 10):

GNU `tar` has `--to-command`. With it you can have `tar` pipe each file from the archive into the given command. For the case where you just want the lines that match, that command can be a simple `grep`. To know the filenames you need to take advantage of tar setting certain variables in the command's environment; for example,

```
tar xaf thing.tar.xz --to-command="awk -e '/thing.to.match/ {print ENVIRON[\"TAR_FILENAME\"] \":\", \$0}'"
```

Because I find myself using this often, I have this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") <pattern> <tarfile>"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -t 1 ]; then
    h="$(tput setf 4)"
    m="$(tput setf 5)"
    f="$(tput sgr0)"
else
    h=""
    m=""
    f=""
fi

tar xaf "$2" --to-command="awk -e '/$1/{gsub(\"$1\", \"$m&$f\"); print \"$h\" ENVIRON[\"TAR_FILENAME\"] \"$f:\", \$0}'"
```

Comment: my awk doesn't take ```-e```, but this is otherwise perfect.

Comment: The `grep` command supports `--label="$TAR_FILENAME"`; no need to use `awk`.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done with `tar --to-command` and `grep --label`:

```sh
tar xaf archive.tar.gz --to-command 'egrep -Hn --label="$TAR_FILENAME" your_pattern_here || true'
```

- `--label` gives grep the filename
- `-H` tells grep to display the filename, and `-n` the line number
- `|| true` because otherwise grep will exit with an error if the pattern is not found, and `tar` will complain about that.
- `xaf` means to extract, and automagically decompress based off the file extension
- `--to-command` has tar pass each file in the tarfile to a separate invocation of grep, and sets various environment variables with info about the file. See [the manpage](https://man.archlinux.org/man/tar.1.en#Output_stream_selection) for more info.

Pretty heavily based off of [Chipaca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23329727/1294423) (and Daniel H's comment), but this should be a bit easier to use and just uses tar and grep.

Answer (score 2):

Python's [`tarfile` module](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) along with [`Tarfile.extractfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractfile) will allow you to inspect the tarball's contents without extracting it to disk.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to use [avfs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/avf/).  I've used this before for such tasks.

Basically, the syntax is:

```
avfsd ~/.avfs # Sets up a avfs virtual filesystem
rgrep pattern ~/.avfs/path/to/file.tar#/
```

`/path/to/file.tar` is the path to the actual tar file.

Pre-pending `~/.avfs/` (the mount point) and appending # lets avfs expose the tar file as a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the TAR archive with [ratarmount](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount) and then simply search for the pattern in the mounted view:

```
pip install --user ratarmount
ratarmount large-archive.tar mountpoint
grep -r '<pattern>' mountpoint/
```

This should be much faster than iterating over each file and printing it to stdout, especially for compressed TARs.

---

Here is a simple comparison benchmark:

```sh
function checkFilesWithRatarmount()
{
    local pattern=$1
    local archive=$2
    ratarmount "$archive" "$archive.mountpoint"
    'grep' -r -l "$pattern" "$archive.mountpoint/"
}

function checkEachFileViaStdOut()
{
    local pattern=$1
    local archive=$2
    tar --list --file "$archive" | while read -r file; do
        if tar -x --file "$archive" -O -- "$file" | grep -q "$pattern"; then
            echo "Found pattern in: $file"
        fi
    done
}

function createSampleTar()
{
    for i in $( seq 40 ); do 
        head -c $(( 1024 * 1024 )) /dev/urandom | base64 > $i.dat
    done
    tar -czf "$1" [0-9]*.dat
}

createSampleTar myarchive.tar.gz
time checkEachFileViaStdOut ABCD myarchive.tar.gz
time checkFilesWithRatarmount ABCD myarchive.tar.gz
sleep 0.5s
fusermount -u myarchive.tar.gz.mountpoint
```

Results in seconds for a 55 MiB uncompressed and 42 MiB compressed TAR archive containing 40 files:

| Compression | Ratarmount | Bash Loop over tar -O |
| --- | --- | --- |
| none | 0.31 +- 0.01 | 0.55 +- 0.02 |
| gzip | 1.1 +- 0.1 | 13.5 +- 0.1 |
| bzip2 | 1.2 +- 0.1 | 97.8 +- 0.2 |

Of course, these results are highly dependent on the archive size and how many files the archive contains. These test examples are pretty small because I didn't want to wait too long but they already show the problem. The more files there are, the longer it takes for `tar -O` to jump to the correct file. And for compressed archives, it will be quadratically slower the larger the archive size is because everything before the requested file has to be decompressed and each file is requested separately. Both of these problems are solved by ratarmount.