# zgrep - list matched file name

Tags: bash, grep

grep or egrep show the filename of the matched file when you define the option "-l".

However, I've got a huge file (tar.gz) which contains thousands of files and I need to find out which of them contains a pattern. The problem is:

```
zgrep -la testPattern HugeFile.tar.gz
```

gives me only the name of the tar.gz file, not the file in it, which matches the pattern.

This seems to be a bug for me, but maybe I misunderstood something… Does anyone know how to do it without gunzipping or untaring the archive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

zgrep'ing a tar.gz will not do what you expect it to do (it is effectively grepping the raw tar image).

You can however take the alternative approach as answered here in other questions:

[Performing grep operation in tar files without extracting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407111/performing-grep-operation-in-tar-files-with-out-extracting)

Answer (score 1):

zgrep is a shell script which use gzip to decompress the files to stdout and pipe into grep. It cannot tell which file inside the tarball hit the match.

One possible way you may try: install the archivemount which use fuse and libarchive, allows you to "mount" a tarball to as if a file system. Then you should be able to grep under the mount point. I didn't try it before, but its better than untar everything for a grep.