# How to grep for a pattern in the files in tar archive without filling up disk space

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

I have a tar archive which is very big ~ 5GB.

I want to grep for a pattern on all files (and also print the name of the file that has the pattern ) in the archive but do not want to fill up my disk space by extracting the archive.

Anyway I can do that?

I tried these, but this does not give me the file names that contain the pattern, just the matching lines:

```
tar -O -xf test.tar.gz | grep 'this'
tar -xf test.tar.gz --to-command='grep awesome'
```

Also where is this feature of tar documented? tar xf test.tar $FILE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407111/performing-grep-operation-in-tar-files-with-out-extracting

Comment: @OpDeCirkel Where is this feature of tar documented? tar xf test.tar $FILE

Comment: Got to the examples section (last example): http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar

Comment: Generally, the man page for `tar` does not explain even _appending_ files properly. .... specifically, the man page that comes with my linux dist it has `[pathname ...]` and no furthure explanation, but if append works (also not documented), than you can try extract too..... you have to read [Unix Haters Handbook](http://simson.net/ref/ugh.pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my take on this:

```
while read filename; do tar -xOf file.tar "$filename" | grep 'pattern' | sed "s|^|$filename:|"; done < <(tar -tf file.tar | grep -v '/$')
```

Broken out for explanation:

- `while read filename; do` -- it's a loop...
- `tar -xOf file.tar "$filename"` -- this extracts each file...
- `| grep 'pattern'` -- here's where you put your pattern...
- `| sed "s|^|$filename:|";` - prepend the filename, so this looks like grep. Salt to taste.
- `done < <(tar -tf file.tar | grep -v '/$')` -- end the loop, get the list of files as  to fead to your `while read`.

One proviso: this breaks if you have OR bars (`|`) in your filenames.

Hmm.  In fact, this makes a nice little bash function, which you can append to your `.bashrc` file:

```
targrep() {

  local taropt=""

  if [[ ! -f "$2" ]]; then
    echo "Usage: targrep pattern file ..."
  fi

  while [[ -n "$2" ]]; do    

    if [[ ! -f "$2" ]]; then
      echo "targrep: $2: No such file" >&2
    fi

    case "$2" in
      *.tar.gz) taropt="-z" ;;
      *) taropt="" ;;
    esac

    while read filename; do
      tar $taropt -xOf "$2" \
       | grep "$1" \
       | sed "s|^|$filename:|";
    done < <(tar $taropt -tf $2 | grep -v '/$')

  shift

  done
}
```

Comment: I hate thanks on SO, but this one really helped me out - thx (:

Answer (score 14):

Seems like nobody posted this simple solution that **processes the archive only once:**

```
tar xzf archive.tgz --to-command \
    'grep --label="$TAR_FILENAME" -H PATTERN ; true'
```

Here `tar` passes the name of each file in a variable (see [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-an-External-Program.html#SEC84)) and it is used by `grep` to print it with each match. Also `true` is added so that `tar` doesn't complain about failing to extract files that don't match.

Comment: Best answer, works perfectly and as intended by tar.

Comment: The `; true` isn’t working for me; those are being passed as arguments to `grep`, which complains about `;` and `true` not being files or directories.

Comment: @DanielH Which shell are you using? This can affect how the command is parsed and run.

Comment: `zsh`, but it seems more like the kind of thing which would change between versions of `tar` than between shells. Both `zsh` and `bash` would interpret the single-quoted `grep` command the same way if it were typed in directly.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.  The other answers here and in related (dup?) question https://stackoverflow.com/q/2407111/446767 read the archive multiple times or seemed extra complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bash function that may work for you. Add the following to your `~/.bashrc`

```
targrep () {
    for i in $(tar -tzf "$1"); do
        results=$(tar -Oxzf "$1" "$i" | grep --label="$i" -H "$2")
        echo "$results"
    done
}
```

Usage:

```
targrep archive.tar.gz "pattern"
```

Comment: This does not work. It prints (standard input) as the file name. I tried with -l and -H.

Comment: Doh, I didn't see your bash function before I wrote mine.  And yours is nicer than mine.  :-)  **+1**.  (Now that I check, it seems that FreeBSD's tar automatically recognizes gzipped files, so my filename recognition may be redundant.)

Answer (score 1):

It's incredibly hacky, but you could abuse tar's `-v` option to process and delete each file as it is extracted.

```
grep_and_delete() {
  if [ -n "$1" -a -f "$1" ]; then
    grep -H 'this' -- "$1" </dev/null
    rm -f -- "$1" </dev/null
  fi
}
mkdir tmp; cd tmp
tar -xvzf test.tar.gz | (
  prev=''
  while read pathname; do
    grep_and_delete "$prev"
    prev="$pathname"
  done
  grep_and_delete "$prev"
)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407111/performing-grep-operation-in-tar-files-with-out-extracting

Comment: This way is faster because it only decompresses the `.tar.gz` file once.

Answer (score 1):

```
tar -tf test.tar.gz | grep -v '/$'| \
xargs -n 1 -I _ \
sh -c 'tar -xOf test.tar.gz _|grep -q <YOUR SEARCH PATTERN>  && echo _'
```

Comment: Can you please answer my question in the comment of original post ?

Comment: @abc, if it's part of your question, why don't you [add it to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13041068/edit)?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    tar tvf name_of_file |grep --regex="pattern"
```

The t option will test the tar file without extracting the files. The v is verbose and the f prints he filenames. This should save you considerable hard disk space.

Comment: This is not right either. Have you tried this before posting?

Comment: What's wrong with it, @abc?  It doesn't extract the files; it gets the file names on standard output, and greps for them.  What result did you get? Or is the trouble that you want to get the names of the files that contain the pattern in the body of the file without extracting the files...that's harder, but not clearly described in the question.

Comment: This is great for extracting and searching the file name patterns. I found it helpful, since I was looking for just the file names. However, it is correct to say this will not search the contents of the files.

Answer (score 0):

may help

```
zcat log.tar.gz | grep -a -i "string"

zgrep -i "string" log.tar.gz
```

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/9261/grep-compressed-log-files-without-extracting