# Display filename of tar file

Tags: bash

I would like to know how to display the filename along with the lines matching a specfic word of a tar file.

Command wise :

```
zcat file | grep "stuff" -r # shows what I want
zcat *.gz | grep "stuff" -ar # this fails
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider formatting your code with the `{ }` button to increase readability .

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983365/grep-from-tar-gz-without-extracting-faster-one

Comment: That button is in the editor, don't type `{` and `}` :-) You can just put 4 spaces before each line alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zgrep`:

For single file, you can use the following command to display filename:

```
zgrep "stuff" file.gz /dev/null
```

For multiple files:

```
zgrep "stuff" *.gz
```

Comment: It looks like the OP has a tgz. while `zgrep` does a good job grepping inside gzipped files, I don't think it will work well for grepping in files inside a gzipped tarball _and_ print their name.

Comment: Yeah I know, but the OP also wrote "tar file". Maybe I'm wrong and they meant "gz file".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the question is but if you are looking for tar files on your system then just do something like this.  This will recursively search your current directory and any child directories for .tar files.  Hope this helps.

```
find -name "*.tar"
```

Comment: No, it willl not - did you mean `find`? The OP does not want to look for tar files, but grep for an expression inside files _in a_ tar file.

Comment: oops, yes I did
I meant:
find -name "*.tar"

Comment: Now that statement is correct, thanks for editing. I'm just afraid that your post still does not actually answer the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23329727/4024473) can help. It uses `tar` to untar (you would need to add `-z`) and pipes each file of the archive to `awk` for "grepping" inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If `zcat file | grep "stuff" -r` shows what you want, you can do this for multiple files:

```
for name in *.gz ; do zcat "$name" | grep -a "stuff" | sed -e "s/^/${name}: /"  ; done
```

This command uses globbing (`*`) to expand to a list of `.gz` files in your working directory, then calls `zcat` for extraction, `grep` for the search and `sed` for prefixing with the filename on each of the files.

Note that if you are working with gzipped tarballs, most people give them a `.tgz` or `.tar.gz` instead of just `.gz` extension.

Answer (score 0):

This will output nameOfFileInTar:LineNumber:Match. Invoke with `greptar.sh tarfile.tar pattern`

If you don't want the line number, remove the -n option. If you only want the line number, add `|cut -f1 -d:` after the `grep`

```
#!/bin/bash

TARFILE=$1
PATTERN=$2
tar ztf $TARFILE | while read -r FILE
do
  res=$(tar zxf $TARFILE $FILE  -O | grep -n $2 )
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
      echo "$res" | while read -r line; do
        echo $FILE:$line;
      done
    fi
done
```